# How do I base58 encode the chain ID using Python?

Tags: protocol, encoding, base58, python

When Tezos needs to sign a baking or endorsement operation payload, byte 0 will be a 0x01 for a baking operation or 0x02 for an endorsement operation. Bytes 1-5 in the operation payload contain the chain ID (otherwise known as Network), which can be encoded in base58 using [this specification](https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/blob/master/src/lib_crypto/base58.ml#L358):

```
let chain_id = "\087\082\000" (* Net(15) *)
```

The resulting chain ID will be a string like `NetXdQprcVkpaWU` (the currently active mainnet chain ID as of Feb. 16th, 2019).

How do I convert the 4-byte field in bytes 1-5 into the base58 encoded Net(15) format using Vitalik's pybitcointools module?

I've tried using the script in `scripts/b58_prefix.py` to determine the appropriate magicbyte to pass to the `bitcoin.bin_to_b58check` function, but I'm not getting the appropriate result:

```
$ ./b58_prefix.py Net 4
15 5722583 [87L, 81L, 215L]
```

Here is my code:

```
def get_chain_id(self):
    chainid = bytes.fromhex(self.payload[2:10])
    return bitcoin.bin_to_b58check(chainid, magicbyte=5722583)
```

On zeronet, an endorsement payload looks like this: `023bb717ee882891d7be5b881cefa98946800e3d67b5d01b4237b3618709defb51ec37c3e100000518ae`, where `3bb717ee` is the chain id, but that converts to `Net1BPz7FKbUqsY` and it should be `NetXSzLHKwSumh7` on zeronet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your magicbyte seems to be wrong. If you take the decimal byte values from the original, convert them to hex, then pad it with a leading zero, you get

```
>>> struct.unpack('>L', b'\x00\x57\x52\x00')[0]
5722624
```

This value should produce the expected result:

```
>>> payload = '023bb717ee882891d7be5b881cefa98946800e3d67b5d01b4237b3618709defb51ec37c3e100000518ae'
>>> mb = struct.unpack('>L', b'\x00\x57\x52\x00')[0]
>>> chainid = bytes.fromhex(payload[2:10])
>>> bitcoin.bin_to_b58check(chainid, magicbyte=mb)
'NetXSzLHKwSumh7'
```

Comment: Yeah 5722624 is the right magicbyte:

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you are only actually grabbing 2 bytes of data (4 hex chars). I verified this by decoding the result you got, and it only returning two bytes of data for the given magic byte.

Try making the following change:

```
def get_chain_id(self):
    chainid = bytes.fromhex(self.payload[2:10])
    return bitcoin.bin_to_b58check(chainid, magicbyte=5722583)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is part of the problem - I need to grab 8 characters (4 hex bytes), or `self.payload[2:10]`. On zeronet, an endorsement payload looks like this: `023bb717ee882891d7be5b881cefa98946800e3d67b5d01b4237b3618709defb51ec37c3e100000518ae`, where `3bb717ee` is the chain id, but that converts to `Net1BPz7FKbUqsY` and it should be `NetXSzLHKwSumh7` on zeronet.

I edited the question above a bit. Thanks again for all your help.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, many thanks! You've helped me with solving the block signature mystery :)
You can use [pytezos.encoding](https://github.com/baking-bad/pytezos) package:

```
from pytezos.encoding import base58_encode

def get_chain_id(self):
    chainid = bytes.fromhex(self.payload[2:10])
    return base58_encode(chain_id, b'Net')
```