# How is chain_id computed?

Tags: rpc, blockchain

The RPC `GET /chains/<chain_id>/chain_id` returns:

> 'the chain unique identifier'

How is this identifier computed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I base58 encode the chain ID using Python?](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/465/how-do-i-base58-encode-the-chain-id-using-python)

Comment: The answers in the "using Python" version of the question :( do not seem to answer the general question... So I will attempt to answer this one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `chain_id` is computed from the genesis block hash as follows.

First, in pseudocode:

```
tezosB58CheckEncode('Net',
  firstFourBytes(
    blake2b(msg = tezosB58CheckDecode('B', genesisBlockHash),
            size = 32)))
```

In detail:

1. Take the genesis block hash. For example, in mainnet, this is `"BLockGenesisGenesisGenesisGenesisGenesisf79b5d1CoW2"`.
2. `Base58Check-decode` the block hash. The prefix bytes for blocks "B" are [1, 52] (in decimal), as you can see by doing `git grep B\(` in tezos.git. This gives us `0x8fcf233671b6a04fcf679d2a381c2544ea6c1ea29ba6157776ed8424c7ccd00b`.
3. Compute the `BLAKE2B` hash (size 32) of the block hash bytes. We get `0x7a06a7709ff405d1791d856c52a3c55246e03ec913599b813ec2977398afb3be`. Take only the first four bytes, `0x7a06a770`.
4. `Base58Check-encode` these four bytes with the "Net" prefix [87, 82, 0] (`git grep Net\(`). We get `"NetXdQprcVkpaWU"`.

For a protocol update test chain, I believe the 'genesis' block will be the block in the main chain from which the test chain was forked.

You can find this computation defined in [`lib_crypto/chain_id.ml`](https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/blob/e7612c5ffa46570cdcc612f7bcead771edc24283/src/lib_crypto/chain_id.ml#L121) and then used as `Chain_id.of_block_hash` in various places (e.g. [`lib_shell/state.ml`](https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/blob/e7612c5ffa46570cdcc612f7bcead771edc24283/src/lib_shell/state.ml#L1196), [`lib_shell/chain_validator.ml`](https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/blob/e7612c5ffa46570cdcc612f7bcead771edc24283/src/lib_shell/chain_validator.ml#L170), [`lib_storage/context.ml`](https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/blob/e7612c5ffa46570cdcc612f7bcead771edc24283/src/lib_storage/context.ml#L454)).

Comment: thanks for your answer! could you provide if possible for reference a source for this information ?